# Dynamically create a condition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image]

As presented in image above, I am letting the user to create a condition by himself. He can add as much `AND` and `OR` conditions as he wants.

My question is: How can I create a condition query based on user input and validate it. For example, the image above needs to be mapped in:

```
if( condition_1 && condition_2 || condition3 ){

}
```

What is the best way to create a condition query based on user input?

Comment: You could construct a string and then `eval()` it. Just make sure you sanitize all the inputs. Alternately, start with `var result = true`, then loop through each condition: if the logic condition is "and", then `result &&= condition` but if the condition is "or" then `result ||= condition`. Also, have you considered the precedence of "and" vs "or"?

Comment: I think eval could be quite an unsafe solution if the input isn't sanitized perfectly, especially given that there are easier solutions.

Comment: I know about the `eval()`, but I was looking for something similar as your second suggestion. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th easiest way is going to be to store the operator with the user's selected options on everything but the first element (as a single element has no operation done to it). You could store your values as such:

```js
const conditions: Array<{
   question: string;
   logicFunction: string;
   query: string; 
   // Optional because the first element in the array will not have an operator
   operator?: 'AND' | 'OR'; 
}> = [...]
```

Then, once the values are stored in this way, you can use a reducer function to conclude the final result:

```js
const result = conditions.reduce((accumulated, condition, index) => {
    // Here calculate this based on your logicFunction, query, etc.
    const conditionResult = ...;

    // First element has no operator
    if(index === 0) return boolean;

    // Calculate the result based off of the accumulated
    // (based on the pervasively calculated value in the chain)
    if(condition.operator === 'AND') return accumulated && conditionResult;
    if(condition.operator === 'OR') return accumulated || conditionResult;

    // This line should never be reached, so if it is, there was a critical error
    throw new Error('Invalid state, non-first element has no operator');
}, false /* or whatever your default value should be */);
```

Comment: This is kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped you out @NenadMilosavljevic